# UnsatisfiedLinkError with pjSIP can't find org.pjsip.pjsua2.pjsua2JNI.swig_module_init()

Tags: android, pjsip, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I try to include pjSIP into my project, and finally got it to sync properly with Gradle.

But when I try to define an Endpoint based on [the example code from this documentation](http://www.pjsip.org/docs/book-latest/html/intro_pjsua2.html#using-in-java-application) I get an `UnsatisfiedLinkError`. Does this mean that my project misses some files, or what has happenend here? I implemented all files that have been build by swig from the pjSIP project, except for the example-app.
The full error looks like this:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void org.pjsip.pjsua2.pjsua2JNI.swig_module_init() (tried Java_org_pjsip_pjsua2_pjsua2JNI_swig_1module_1init and Java_org_pjsip_pjsua2_pjsua2JNI_swig_1module_1init__)
        at org.pjsip.pjsua2.pjsua2JNI.swig_module_init(Native Method)
        at org.pjsip.pjsua2.pjsua2JNI.<clinit>(pjsua2JNI.java:2159)
        at org.pjsip.pjsua2.Endpoint.<init>(Endpoint.java:68)
        at replacelater.telephonapp.MainActivity.initPJSIP(MainActivity.java:145)
        at replacelater.telephonapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:134)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5953)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1128)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

PJSUA native library is not loaded.Please load the library when you start the application.